# What is the best way of "fusioning" two data frames?

Tags: r

I have two data frames (`df_a` and `df_b`) both containing a number of columns and patient IDs. The columns contain information about particular diagnosis (`TRUE` or `FALSE`). My task is to combine the two data frames so that the value is `TRUE` if the value is `TRUE` in any of the data frames.

In reality there is a different number of rows in `df_a` and `df_b`. The matching should be done using the `id`. Both data frames have the same set of columns.

```
df_a <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 dg_a = c(T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, F, T), 
                 dg_b = c(F, F, F, F, T, T, F, T, T, F))

df_b <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                 dg_a = c(F, F, F, T, F, F, F, T, T, T), 
                 dg_b = c(F, T, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F))
```

I.e. after combining data frames `df_a` and `df_b` I should get `df_c`.

```
>df_c
   id  dg_a  dg_b
1   1  TRUE FALSE
2   2  TRUE  TRUE
3   3  TRUE  TRUE
4   4  TRUE FALSE
5   5 FALSE  TRUE
6   6 FALSE  TRUE
7   7  TRUE FALSE
8   8  TRUE  TRUE
9   9  TRUE  TRUE
10 10  TRUE FALSE
```

What is the best way of doing this in R? I have tried different types of `joins` but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I agree the solution is a variant of that and can be considered a duplicate of the link you provided. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I think this is a good question. I have added a generic/flexible answer in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/48754261#48754261)  question. You can have look. It may help you in cases where you got many columns. I had to add answer to the linked question as this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: I think this is different enough to stand on it's own, perhaps with a note to the more basic/general question. @MKR, I'd suggest moving your answer to this question, as it does not really answer the question you posted it at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very generic solution can be achieved using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

The approach: Since number of columns can be many, hence I think it would be better to first use `gather` to create dataframes in form of `id`, `key` and `val`. Then use `bind_rows` to merger dataframes and apply logic derive value(i.e. even one value is `TRUE` then combined value will be `TRUE`. Finally use `spread` from `tidyr` package to return dataframes in original format.

```
df_a <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                   dg_a = c(T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, F, T), 
                   dg_b = c(F, F, F, F, T, T, F, T, T, F))

df_b <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                   dg_a = c(F, F, F, T, F, F, F, T, T, T), 
                   dg_b = c(F, T, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_a %>% gather(key = "key", value = "val", -id) %>% 
         bind_rows(gather(df_b, key = "key", value = "val", -id )) %>%
         group_by(id, key) %>%
         summarise(val = ifelse(sum(val == TRUE) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
         spread(key, val) %>% as.data.frame()

# Result  

#    id  dg_a  dg_b
# 1   1  TRUE FALSE
# 2   2  TRUE  TRUE
# 3   3  TRUE  TRUE
# 4   4  TRUE FALSE
# 5   5 FALSE  TRUE
# 6   6 FALSE  TRUE
# 7   7  TRUE FALSE
# 8   8  TRUE  TRUE
# 9   9  TRUE  TRUE
# 10 10  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `|` operation:

```
df_c <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                   dg_a = df_a$dg_a | df_b$dg_a,
                   dg_b = df_a$dg_b | df_b$dg_b)
```

Comment: What if I have different number of rows in the data frames (and not all the IDs are the same)?

Comment: @JuusoT You can try my solution (provided as answer in to your question). That solution should be able to handle situations where number of rows are different, IDs are different or even columns are different in two dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution which takes into consideration that you may have a different number of rows in both data.frames:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df_a, df_b, by = "id") %>%
    transmute(id,
              dg_a = dg_a.x | dg_a.y,
              dg_b = dg_b.x | dg_b.y)
```

This will include rows from both data.frames even if there isn't a match; see the other `dplyr` join functions for other behaviors.